# Embed survey email

Tags: email, outlook, embed, survey

I am trying to embed a survey into an email (outlook 2007). When they complete the survey the answers are stored somewhere I can manage (Like the use of forms in Google drive).

I have tried creating a custom form, I do not have access to the organizational form library.

I have tried using the voting system inbuilt in out look which would work if only multiple answers could be selected rather than just 1.

The Google forms does exactly what I need, I just have to use outlook.

I'm hoping I am just missing something because I cannot see a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work. Check out the list at the bottom of this page: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/

Edit: From the same article:

> Given the sporadic support for forms in emails, we recommend linking
>   to a form on a website rather than embedding it in the email. This is
>   the safest, most reliable solution to pairing an email message with a
>   form. More people will see it and be able to use it, and as a result
>   participation will increase.

Comment: +1. I speak with 15 years of email marketing experience and I can tell you that forms and emails just don't mix.

Comment: Thanks guys, firstly why is this on hold? have I done something wrong?

Comment: Secondly I ended up using Microsoft info path to populate a database from emails :)